# Variables variables through pipes c#

Tags: c#, linux, mono

Hi i'm trying to use pipes to redirect standard output and standard error from a process, so far I made it possible to send and receive data using `Console.ReadLine()` from server to client pipes but i've been looking for a away to send variables (like the standard output/error)

NamedPipeClient:

```
static void client(){
    while (true){
        var clientStream = new NamedPipeClientStream("ouput");
        clientStream.Connect(60);
        string line = Console.ReadLine();
        byte[] buffer = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(line);
        clientStream.Write(buffer,0,buffer.Length);
        if (line.ToLower() == "cerrar")
            break;
        clientStream.Close();
    }
}
```

Server Pipe:

```
static void server(){
    while (true){
        var namedPipeServerStream = new NamedPipeServerStream("output");
        namedPipeServerStream.WaitForConnection();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[255];
        namedPipeServerStream.Read(buffer, 0, 255);
        string request = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer);
        Console.WriteLine(request);
        request=request.Trim('\0');
        if(request.ToLower()=="cerrar")
            break;
        namedPipeServerStream.Close();
    }
}
```

This is how I get to start a process:

```
Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
process.StartInfo.FileName = "/bin/bash";
process.StartInfo.Arguments = "-c " + pathFile + " \"";
process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
process.Start();
string output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
string error = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
process.WaitForExit();
```

The idea is to take the vars `output` and `error` and send them by the pipes I have.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: why you use `NamedPipeClientStream` in server and use `NamedPipeServerStream` in client?

Comment: Thank you for pointing it out, I fix it